# How Can I Use A SQL Database Like I Used To Use Access?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have been supporting a product written in VB6 with an Access database for a long time. In many of the installations a mapped drive was used to allow multiple workstations to run simultaneously. Since it seems Microsoft has broken that recently, I need to re-write everything with a new set of tools.

I plan to use VB.net and I would like to use a SQL database this time for the stability. The problem is that the market I sell to cannot / will not support installing full blown SQL Server and all the complexities of managing it.

What I am not able to find any current info about is whether or not SQL Server Compact still exists, whether or not it can be added to a NON web based project and if it will be easy to deploy and be easy to manage like an Access database was.

When I try to follow the directions to add SQL Server Compact to my project, it isn't available in the Data Source drop down list (there are "Simple by ErikEJ" versions listed but they don't seem to work) I have seen SQL Server Compact talked about with regards to web projects but I am building a locally installed .exe. I can't find ANY current info about what flavors of SQL are available right now to add to a local program running over a peer to peer network.

Comment: SQL Compact still exists according to a simple google https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=17876 and is available for desktop apps. However you can't share it between applications. SQL Server is not file based like Access and requires the SQL Server service to access it which would require SQL Server Express (free but needs to be installed and potentially maintained somewhere on the network).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, SQL Server CE can still be used but is no longer supported. For file-based databases, Microsoft currently recommend SQLite.

For a multi-user system, SQL Server Express is probably your best bet.  It's still server-based though, so the server needs to be installed somewhere.  For local databases, you can install on the same machine as the application and attach a data file on demand.  For multiple clients, you'll need the server installed on a machine accessible to all and a permanently-attached database.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input!  I'm just a self taught guy so I'm pretty lost right now.  It sounds like Express is as close as I can get.  I'll try putting something together to test it out.  I really appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Compact is no longer supported and developed by Microsoft, I suggest that you use SQL Server Express, it allows remote connections (if configured to allow it) and has modest resource requirements. Supports a database up to 10 GB of size.